# How to optimize the following eloquent query?

Tags: php, laravel

I have multi query like this:

```
$source = Wallet:findOrFail($request->sourceId);
$des = Wallet:findOrFail($request->desId);

$fee = !empty($request->feeId) ? Wallet:findOrFail($request->feeId) : null;
```

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: This is 3 individual queries, it's not terribly un-optimal. You _could_ condense it to a single query using `whereIn('id', [$request->sourceId, $request->desId])` (with conditional logic to include or ignore `$request->feeId`), but you'd still have to sort out which is which is `$source`, `$des` and `$fee` from the returned results after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do multiple things here are some:

1. Use index on the table for all three columns.
2. Fetch all once in one query and apply filters.

   ```
   $wallets = Wallet:all();

   // filter through $wallets for the sourceId, desId and feeId.
   ```
3. is @Tim solution